# while loop comparing two numbers from a string

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to create a simple bash script to run through a loop until size1=size2

I have a variable that I'm trying to extract size1 and size2

`strvar=Size: 367.3 MiB/367.3 MiB Time: 2.04`

can I use parameter expansion to extract just the numbers on each side of the "/" and split into two variables (size1,size2)?  It's ok if the MiB stays as long as I can evaluate if size1 is the same as size2.

the variable `$strvar` is the output from a command.  I use `strvar=$(command | grep Size)` to get it.

Comment: Where does the string come from and why do you have it in a variable?  If it's the output of a program, then the check could be done directly in a pipeline, reading from that program, depending on what it is you'd like to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
read size1 unit1 size2 unit2 <<< $(command | sed -n '/Size/ {s/^[^ ]* //; s/ Time:.*$//; s#/# #; p}')
```

?

Comment: Just FYI, @RudiC (and feel free to flag this as "no longer necessary"), some of your answers are showing up in the "low quality" review queue, likely because the post is largely code. If you provide a bit of commentary to explain what the code is doing, you'll be at less risk of someone voting to delete the answer.  On a side note, my (opinion/suggestion) would be to rephrase the text to be more of a statement than a question. It could confuse someone who's reviewing too quickly and thinks you're asking a question of the OP instead of answering. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Jeff Schaller for these hints. I acknowledge there may be (unwritten) rules in these fora, but there's a (my?) personal approach / style as well. Not feeling too comfortable discussing via comments, and not knowing the ropes in here - is there a forum / room for such discussion?

Comment: There is a U&L chat room, at https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat .  It's occasionally busy, but often quiet. I think there may also be a way to create a separate room, although I'm not as familiar with that.  Feel free to ping me in chat (join the room, then send something @JeffSchaller) if you'd like to discuss anything further!